# What items work with Voodoo Jester's ultimate ability?

Tags: heroes-of-newerth

I know you can activate Shrunken head before channeling the ultimate to prevent most interrupts (there are a few superior magic stuns though).

But what about Assassin's Shroud?  Can it be used immediately before/after activating the ult to be invisible?

What about the Void Talisman, can it be activated while channeling without interrupting?

I guess that would be another way to reword the primary question.  What items can be activated without breaking channeling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Void Talisman` will interrupt channeling afaik (using Void Talisman and then teleporting will break the Void Talisman.)

Not interrupting:

1. `Assassin's Shroud` / `Genjuro` since it is based on Windwalk. When used before Voodoo Jester's ultimate your hero will get visible again. When used after Voodoo Jester's ultimate your hero becomes and stays invisible for the Shroud duration.
2. `Barbed Armor`. Can be used at any time.
3. `Energizer`. Can be used at any time.

Since i play a lot of Dota 2 and HoN i tend to mix some facts up. So please correct me if i am wrong.